# removing runtime discovered tests labeled with "rt"

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

We are facing the issue that Xcode detects runtime tests.
Because of certain states of the tests these tests will always fail.

It's not possible to get rid of them, by cleaning the Project nor deleting the Derived Data.

Some Test classes are inherited by others.

Specs:

- Xcode 8.3.3
- Swift 3.1

---

## Edit

#### Add more specific details

Subclass:

- `TestClassA: XCTestCase`

  - `func testA1()`
  - `func testA2()`
- `TestClassB: TestClassA`

  - `func testB1()`

Now the Problem is that when I run all tests for `TestClassB` Xcode will run `testB1` and then `testA1` and `testA2`. Both marked with `rt` and they will fail.

How can i achieve that this is not happening by not loosing the subclass structure.

---

## Screenshot

[image: Tests Screenshot]

Comment: Any comment on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're overriding the setup and teardown do assure the app will be in the proper state for every test case, the problem here would be that 
the rT test will appear since the subclasses are inheriting the tests from their parent.

To avoid this while maintaining the subclassing structure, keep the setup and teardown functions in the classes you have but move the tests to a subclass of the setup class.

For example:

Subclass:

- `TestClassA: XCTestCase` // This one will have the setup and teardown for A
- `TestClassATests: TestClassA`

  - `func testA1()`
  - `func testA2()`
- `TestClassB: TestClassA` // This one will have the setup and teardown for B, and you may reuse A setup
- `TestClassBTests: TestClassB`

  - `func testB1()`
  - `func testB2()`